# How to process and download very large file?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, browser, signalr, task-queue

I am wondering what approach to take

problem flow :

- I have a web API which can accept request from the client
- The API layer talks to business layer and then to data layer
- Data layer Gets huge record set (5000000 rows) , now the business layer 
   process the columns and rows (using maximum threads of the processor)
- once processed the API streams the content as an excel/csv to the client (browser)

Right now the entire download happens in one flow (fire and wait till response is ready)

I would like to isolate this huge business operation of processing 5000000 rows to a separate engine or task queue (I don't want my web site to fall to out of memory  exception) , also I would like to make the user experience smooth.

Trying to use server push events/signalr/or browser long polling , so that I can push the file once the data/file is processed  and ready .

Is there any better way to achieve the same?

Comment: Right now, after the record set gets to the browser, what happens to it, is it displayed just like an excel table?

Comment: the records are emitted as stream  ,with file type as excel/csv

Comment: You can use MSMQ. Put all the clients request data in the message, send message to the MSMQ queue, and process the message on the other side. On the other side, get all the rows (I suppose that these 5000000 rows are the result of the request and not something that client uploads), process them and use a different queue to return the result to your signalr endpoint. I used similar solution with WCF and it works quite nice.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few suggestions based on what I can understand

1. **Serialization.** I would not recommend to respond back with a CSV or Excel format for such a large dataset, unless it is the only format the client can handle. If you have some control over the workflow, I would change the client to accept a format such as JSON, or better yet go even more optimized serializers that are data and speed efficient  like ProtoBuff, Avro, Thrift, etc.
2. **Pagination.** (Assuming you are able to implement the above suggestion.) Usually responding back with large data can hinder performance across the board. It is very common for an API to accept parameters to define the page number and page size. In your case, you could make a unique reference id for the query (ex. "query-001" and that can be called upon `/api/query/001?page=10&items-per-page=10000`).
3. **Caching.** If the query is made frequently, in order to reduce hitting your data layer with every query (for example, requesting different pages). You could either load the data onto the disk or keep the data in memory. Keeping a cache will significantly improve performance and could also reduce complex debugging problems when it comes to performance tuning the system.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ,1. with Serialization my concern is if the output is too large even the java script variable (in-fact browser may throw out of memory exception ) gets flooded  2.  I cannot use pagination as I am expecting an excel report